# MongoDB index usage for find and sort

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a query where the find() uses different document properties then the sort.

e.g.

```
document = { a : "", b : "", c : "", d : "", e : ""}

db.col.find({a : "", b : "", c : ""}).sort({d:1, e:1})
```

Can I create two indexes, one for find() and one for sort(), and will MongoDB use them accordingly?

```
db.col.createIndex({a : 1, b : 1, c : 1})
db.col.createIndex({d:1, e:1})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB (as at 3.0) cannot use multiple indexes (aka "index intersection") when the `sort()` operation requires an index completely separate from the query predicate. You can confirm what indexes are being considered (and the winning plan) using MongoDB's [explain functionality](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/):

```
db.col.find({a : "", b : "", c : ""}).sort({d:1, e:1}).explain(true)
```

For your example, that means that the ideal compound index would probably be a single index on `{a:1, b:1, c:1, d:1, e:1}`.

For more details see:

- [Index Intersection & Sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-sort) in the MongoDB documentation
- [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](http://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/) - a blog post which predates index intersection, but still applies to the query & sort you have described.

Answer (score 0):

Yes mongodb will be using both the indexes for the different purposes. One of the rules for adding index is like below

The order of fields in an index should be:

First, fields on which you will query for exact values.
Second, fields on which you will sort.
Finally, fields on which you will query for a range of values.